# PlantUML - Component diagram with component with inner component in center

Tags: diagram, plantuml

I want to have a component diagram with one component **with an inner component** (nested component) at the center and one component on each side (top, right, down, left) pointing to the center component.

This is what I've tried:

```
@startuml

' Definition der Akteure (Benutzer)
node Browser as Browser1
actor Benutzer as user

' Definition der Fremdsysteme
node "Fremdsystem (Open Source)" as ExternalSystem1
node "Fremdsystem (zugekauft)" as ExternalSystem2
node "Fremdsystem (zugekauft)" as ExternalSystem3

' Definition des zentralen Systems
rectangle "<size:10>      <<system>></size> \n\n  Hauptsystem" as HS {

}


' Interaktionen zwischen Benutzern und dem System
user -right-> Browser1 : " nutzt"
Browser1 -down-> HS : " HTTPS"

' Interaktionen zwischen Fremdsystemen und dem System
ExternalSystem1 <-right- HS : " HTTPS"
ExternalSystem2 <-left- HS : " HTTPS"
ExternalSystem3 <-up- HS : " SMTP"

@enduml
```

[image: Without Inner Component]

But when I'm inserting the inner component (Forum) to the rectangle like this:

```
@startuml

' Definition der Akteure (Benutzer)
node Browser as Browser1
actor Benutzer as user

' Definition der Fremdsysteme
node "Fremdsystem (Open Source)" as ExternalSystem1
node "Fremdsystem (zugekauft)" as ExternalSystem2
node "Fremdsystem (zugekauft)" as ExternalSystem3

' Definition des zentralen Systems
rectangle "<size:10>      <<system>></size> \n\n  Hauptsystem" as HS {
   [Forum]
}


' Interaktionen zwischen Benutzern und dem System
user -right-> Browser1 : " nutzt"
Browser1 -down-> HS : " HTTPS"

' Interaktionen zwischen Fremdsystemen und dem System
ExternalSystem1 <-right- HS : " HTTPS"
ExternalSystem2 <-left- HS : " HTTPS"
ExternalSystem3 <-up- HS : " SMTP"

@enduml
```

[image: With inner component]

It's totally screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something closer to what you want, but I can't tell you exactly why it works or precisely how I got there. Here is more or less what I did:

- The system is now a node.
- Links go to the component (`[Forum] as HS`) which is not really what you had from the original (system is the HS), but I suspect this is OK for you.
- I played around with the order of the `HS` associations to the left and right until I found something that works. It's easiest to do this in an editor that gives immediate rendering (see the link when you click the image below)

```
@startuml
' Definition der Akteure (Benutzer)
node Browser as Browser1
actor Benutzer as user

' Definition der Fremdsysteme
node "Fremdsystem (Open Source)" as ExternalSystem1
node "Fremdsystem (zugekauft)" as ExternalSystem2
node "Fremdsystem (zugekauft)" as ExternalSystem3

' Definition des zentralen Systems
node "Hauptsystem" <<system>> {
   [Forum] as HS
}


' Interaktionen zwischen Benutzern und dem System
user -right-> Browser1 : " nutzt"
Browser1 -down-> HS : " HTTPS"

' Interaktionen zwischen Fremdsystemen und dem System
HS -left-> ExternalSystem1 :  "HTTPS              "
HS -right-> ExternalSystem2 : "              HTTPS"
ExternalSystem3 <-up- HS : " SMTP"
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML image]